# problens whit phpmyadmin permissions

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm starting with database and I am probably doing wrong things in the programs.
I have a database that I developed in php MyAdmin, then I opened it in MySQL and the console. So I changed user authorizations in phpMyadmin and created a lot of problems for my life. Now when I open this one and it doesn't find my database informing me of the following: # 1143 - 'SELECT' command denied for user 'mysql.infoschema'@' localhost 'in column' default_collation_id ', in the table' character_sets'.

In the console I try to see my databases (mysql> show databases;) and I get the answer: ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'information_schema.SCHEMATA' references invalid table (s) or column (s) or function (s) or definer / invoker of view lack rights to use them

MySQL Workbench also disappeared with my bank (I was able to recreate it through the script) and now I have problems making dumps (mysqldum.exe is version 8.0.20, but the MwSQL Server to be dumped has version 10.4.10).
Help!
Well, I don't know if the problems are related, I've been trying to solve all this for a few days and I can't.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, first a few questions for you. When you changed the user authorizations, what exactly did you modify? What user are you connecting as? When you say "In the console..." do you mean the text that says "Console" at the bottom of the phpMyAdmin window, or using the system console/terminal/shell ? What operating system are you using? MySQL Workbench disappearing seems quite unrelated to these other problems, as an aside, since MySQL permissions wouldn't affect what programs you have installed on your local computer.

Comment: Hi Issac!    When you changed the user authorizations, what exactly did you modify?  I don't remember. I don't know exactly how I arrived at this authorizations.What user are you connecting as?   To connect in phpMyadmin I use root and password is enter.When you say "In the console..." do you mean the text that says "Console" at the bottom of the phpMyAdmin window, or using the system console/terminal/shell ?  The system console
What operating system are you using? I use windows 10 pro.

Comment: MySQL Workbench disappearing seems quite unrelated to these other problems, as an aside, since MySQL permissions wouldn't affect what programs you have installed on your local computer.  I changed the authorizations in php Myadmin only.  In MySQL Workbench don't let me salve the dump. It say " Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema (1109)

Operation failed with exitcode 2".
I hope I have answered your questions. Let me know if you need to understand anything else.Thank you!

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled workbench and wampserver. Everything's solved!